# Reflection on .class field

Tags: java, reflection

Reading on class loading, http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/01/26/classloading.html, came across - 
"......Whenever we compile any Java file, the compiler will embed a public, static, final field named class, of the type java.lang.Class, in the emitted byte code. Since this field is public, we can access it using dotted notation, like this:

java.lang.Class klass = Myclass.class;
............"

i tried accessing this field (Myclass.class) using reflection, which is plain insane i agree but still :) and i get java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: class

```
Myclass myObject = new Myclass; 
System.out.println(myObject.getclass().getField("class"));
```

Is it then the runtime and not the compiler that adds the static .class field? Even then why is it not accessible using reflection?

Comment: Field name is klass and accessing class !

Comment: @bunta edited the question for clarity

Comment: just wondering why you need .class from reflection when you already have getClass()

Comment: No i don need it. i just like to try :) but anyways as it turns out .class is an expression and not necessarily a field as the onjava article claims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a field access, per se, but rather an [expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2) of the Java language syntax that merely looks like a field access. I suppose it's possible for a compiler to put such a synthetic field into the classfile, though I don't know of one that does.

Comment: hmmm... would make much more sense that ways.. thnx. Need to read the specs, no other go :)

Answer (score 0):

In general, the Java language specification says that an expression of this form must return the corresponding class object, but it does not define how this has to be done. The Eclipse JDT compiler actually does not make it a field. It creates a method called "$class" that is called whenever you access something like myClass.class.